# Why Laravel reply 200 http code when MethodNotAllowedHttpException?

Tags: laravel, routes, postman

Why Laravel reply 200 http code when MethodNotAllowedHttpException?
I Would like to recieve a diferent code, like 500.

I consume laravel routes using angular or postman, and recieve 200 code and is dificult to deal with this.

Below one example:
[image]

Comment: Share your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a error, but the usage of the `dd()` dump and die helper method. This will always return a 200.

Find all `dd();` methods in your project and it should work and return a proper error code. But secondly due to that error being thrown, it could seem like your `url` is invalid and or not allowing POST calls.